# How to do group capture in xpath

Tags: xpath

I am looking for something in xpath can do: `//foo[@n="$1"]//bar[@n="$2"]`
which can return me `$1` and `$2`.  Or at least return me both `<foo>` and `<bar>`

Here is more detail, I have a xml document:

```
<xml>
  <foo>
    <a n="1">
      <b n="1"/>
      <b n="2"/>
    </a>
  </foo>
  <a n="2">
    <b n="1"/>
  </a>
  <a n="3">
    <b n="1"/>
    <foo>
      <b n="2"/>
    </foo>
    <b n="3"/>
  </a>
</xml>
```

I want generate a string base on the n attribute in `<a>` and `<b>`
So I have xpath: `//a[@n]//b[@n]`
Then for every result I get back, I use: `./@n` and `./ancestor::a/@n` to get the info I want.

This is working fine, but I need something more intelligent, because I have a lot structure like this, and need auto generate the xpath.

So for above example, I am looking for some xpath like: `//a[@n="$1"]//b[@n="$2"]`
Then return me:
`(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)

Comment: Please escape inline code with ` characters (see the help info that pops up when posting a question) otherwise the browser tries to format your XML as HTML and it's invisible. I've edited it, but it's awaiting moderation. And can you confirm the output structure you want?

Comment: Utkanos: Yes, this is the format I want. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Dimitre Novatchev: My question is can I do something like: `//a[@n="$1"]//b[@n="$2"]`, which will return me all the `<b>` which inside a `<a>` and give me $1 $2 without any other query.

Comment: @user1508210: From your comment above it isn't clear what the exact wanted result must be. Please, edit the question and provide *the exact* wanted result. As of now I have been straining my guessing powers ... :)

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: Sorry about that. I edit my question, is this more clear ?

Comment: @user1508210: Yes, it is clear now, thanks. The wanted result cannot be produced with a single XPath 1.0 expression. I think this result can be produced with a single XPath 2.0 expression -- are you interested in an XPath 2.0 solution?

Comment: @user1508210: See the update to my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Here is one XPath 1.0 expression that selects all wanted `n` attributes:**

```
//a[.//b]/@n | //a//b/@n
```

Without optimization the evaluation of the above expression performas at least two complete traversals of the XML document.

**This XPath 1.0 expression may be more efficient**:

```
//*[self::a and .//b or self::b and ancestor::a]/@n
```

**Both expressions can be simplified if it is guaranteed that every `a` has a `b` descendant**.

They become, respectively:

```
//a/@n | //a//b/@n
```

And:

```
//*[self::a or self::b and ancestor::a]/@n
```

**Further simplification is possible if it is guaranteed that every `a` has a descendant `b` and every `b` has an ancestor `a`.**:

```
//*[self::a or self::b]/@n
```

**It is impossible in a single XPath 1.0 expression to get the string values of all the wanted attributes**. One needs to get all the atributes using one of the above expressions, then on each of the selected attributes apply a second XPath expression: `string()`.

**In Xpath 2.0 it is possible to get with a single expression all string values of the wanted attributes** -- by simply appending each of the expressions with `/string(.)`

For example, for the simplest one:

```
//(a|b)/@n/string(.)
```

**Update**:

The OP has clarified his question. Now we know that he wants this result to be produced:

> ```
> (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)
> ```

It isn't possible to produce the wanted result with a single XPath 1.0 expression.

**The following XPath 2.0 expression produces the wanted result**:

```
for $a in //a[@n and .//b[@n]],
    $b in $a//b[@n]
  return
     concat('(', $a/@n, ',', $b/@n, ') ')
```

Comment: Thanks for you replay, this is a lot more cleaner than what I have now. But this won't guarantee every `<a>` has at least one `<b>` inside. And it will return something like: `[1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3]`, which is hard to tell first 1 is belong to `<a>`, next 1 2 is belong to `<b>`. Is there anything work like regex group capture ?

Comment: @user1508210: It was my *guess* that you wanted this result -- as you haven't shown us the exact wanted result. Please, edit the question and provide this important and currently missing information. Also, you need to know that XPath is only a query language for XML documents. As such it cannot alter the structure of an XML document or create new XML documents/nodes. If you want a new document created, with structure that is appropriate for your wanted result, you will need to use another language -- the best suited for such purpose language is XSLT.